# Laravel: Select results based on input parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a search query in my controller

```
public function byQuery($query)
    {
        $q = $this->prepareQuery($query);
        if(str_contains($q,'zealand'))
        {
        $q = 'nz';
        }
        $titles = Title::where('suburb', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('postcode', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', $q);

        if (isset($input['type']) && $input['type'] != '')
        {
            $titles = $titles->where('type', 'like', '%'. $input['type'].'%');
        } 
            $titles = $titles->orderBy('href', 'ASC')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
                    ->paginate(36);

            return $titles;

    }
```

If I search for search like

```
search?q=new zealand
```

It will return all the results in my DB which match new zealand

If I search for

```
   search?q=new zealand&type=sold
```

I want if to return all the results from my DB which match new zealand and the type is sold.

So far it's not working.  It only returns all the results from my DB and doesn't limit them to just the sold results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$input` is not defined (at least, I don't see it in the code you posted), so the `isset()` will always return `false`. Use the Input class, which already can do the checking:

```
if (Input::has('type'))
{
   $titles = $titles->where('type', 'like', '%'. rawurldecode(Input::get('type')).'%');
}
```

**Note:** I added a `rawurldecode()` since from your example 'new zealand' would be passed down as 'new+zealand', and this needs be taken into account if you want it to match correctly.

Comment: Hi Damien thanks for the help.  I've added the INPUT class to my namespace and replaced the old input code with yours, but it's still not returning the right results?

Comment: If you run the generated query against the db does it find results?

Comment: yes.. i have four types sold,buy,rent,offer they all have results, but the query will not separate them, it'll return all four types

Comment: It might mean you're not building the query correctly (check the generated sql)

Comment: Hi Damien could it be I'm using ->orWhere('postcode', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', $q)
                                ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', $q); so the query will return where the type is 'sold' orwhere country like new zealand and type is 'buy'?

Comment: Exaclty, that's what I was trying to say. I can't help on that without knowing how you want the query to be laid out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55748/discussion-between-user3664594-and-damien-pirsy).